# What are your favorite Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard

What are your favorite keyboard shortcuts on Mac OS X?

Comment: Putting only one shortcut (or a couple of related ones) in each answer will make the poll more useful.

Comment: Noting, of course, that all of these are fully customizable.

Answer (score 45):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>: Access the menu via the keyboard (Windows <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> equivalent).

Comment: +1 - This tip alone has just totally justified getting involved in the beta. I don't know how I haven't found this previously, but I have often wanted to access the menu without a mouse.

Comment: PS: There's a list of all Mac OS Keyboard Shortcuts available at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343

Comment: It only selects apple menu, but nothing shows up :(

Comment: And then you can move around the menus with the arrow keys, press Enter to expand a menu, and again Enter to run a command.

Comment: Ctrl+F3 focuses the dock (and shows it if it's autohidden)

Comment: Depending on you keyboard and key bindings, you might need to press `Ctrl` + `function (fn)` + `F2`

Comment: Ctrl-f3 gives you access to the dock

Comment: Wow! I've looked for this!

Comment: I really want to change this to `alt`

Comment: In newer versions of Mac OS, you can also do Cmd+Shift+? to bring up the Help menu directly, and then use its built-in expose to search for a command then select it with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 40):

Typing <kbd>/</kbd> on any file dialog will give you a "go to folder" dialog, which autocompletes with <kbd>tab</kbd> (you have to wait a second for it to work). This lets you type in the full path, from the root `/` folder.

Extra handy if you want to open from / save to hidden locations or already have the command line path you want to save something in.

This can be also accessed via <kbd>~</kbd> (i.e. the tilde key, to start from your home directory, e.g. `~/Documents`) or using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (which starts with the most recently entered directory).

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME. And SO MUCH better than Ctrl+Shift+G or whatever it is... (hence why it's so much better). I wish I could up-vote you 230986 times!

Comment: This is also works with "~"

Comment: I've never been more excited about a forward slash. I'll try and fail to  express my excitement about this shortcut to my wife when I get home.

Answer (score 30):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>: activate spotlight.

Then you can launch any application, open most files, do quick calculations, etc.

Answer (score 26):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>: selective screenshot saved on desktop

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>: selective screenshot  saved in clipboard

Comment: As an add on: `Cmd+Shift+4` and then a `space` converts the mouse pointer into a "Camera". Clicking on a window with this "Camera" pointer creates a screenshot of only that window.

Comment: Changing the `4` to a `3` makes an image of the whole screen immediately (no mouse selection) if you're into that kinda thing.

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: show/hide hidden files on any file dialog

Comment: Good one! I wish this shortcut also worked in finder windows.

Comment: @Senseful You can set the `AppleShowAllFiles` key in `com.apple.Finder` to `true` to enable this in the finder. Then restart the finder.

Comment: I couldnt get it to work, am I doing something wrong? I go to the relevant finder window and hit this shortcut

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>: Cycle through running apps

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>: Cycle through windows for current app

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: Close current window

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>: Quit current app

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>: Preferences dialog for current app

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>: Hide current app (as long as it's not Photoshop)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd>: Sleep all displays

Comment: I guess there isn't an alternative for the Sleep all displays for the new MBA's which don't have an eject button anymore? I've setup a Hot Corner which does this, but would prefer a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @DonnaLea, there is alternative. Press power button instead of eject. So it's Ctrl+Shift+Power.

Answer (score 17):

## Power keys:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd>:  "Are you sure you want to shut down your computer" dialog message appears:

[image: power dialog]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd>: restart the computer

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⏏</kbd>: shut down the computer

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd>: puts the computer in sleep mode

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd>: puts the monitor in sleep mode

Comment: Thanks for Shift-Ctrl-Eject, I was looking for something like that.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. I've been looking for ways to quickly turn off my computer.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Esc ⎋</kbd> brings up the force quit dialog, which is handy for killing unresponsive applications.
[image: Force quit applications]

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Esc ⎋</kbd> held down for 5 seconds kills the foremost application.

Comment: I use it all the time!

Comment: Awesome!  How can I have not known about this my whole life?

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>: High contrast theme.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick): Cycle through app's windows.

Comment: I love ctrl-alt-cmd-8; we used to do that at all the computers to joke people, but if you're working at night it works well too.

Comment: The kids in our school call it the x-ray mode.

Comment: +1 for the cmd+backtick shortcut, I've wondered about such a command for a long time!

Comment: Cmd + shift + ´ on swedish layout

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>: Create a new folder in Finder

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>: hide all inactive application windows

This is great for focusing on a single task or works well as a kind of show desktop if you switch to Finder first (providing you have few or no windows open)

Answer (score 9):

For me the life saving shortcut is the quarter increment/decrement of light/sound:

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd> and the increment/decrement light or sound button.

It is extremely useful with LED Cinema Display monitors.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?) on my late 2011 MacBook Air running 10.7.1.

Comment: I have not tried in 10.7 yet, but I would be surprised if it is not working.

Comment: Not working here on OS X Lion either.

Comment: It's working again in 10.7.4.

Comment: Was gone in Lion, seems to be back in Mountain Lion.

Comment: @IainDawson: It came back before, 10.7 is Lion and it's back since version 10.7.4.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: Put selected text into search clipboard.

Then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to find next.
In combination with regular copy-paste you can do selective search and replace very quickly and conveniently.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a great one (for switchers) I got from the [TextMate blog](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/);

Create the folder ~/Library/KeyBindings (if it doesn't already exist)
In there, create a key-binding file DefaultKeyBinding.dict
In that file, put this text (including all braces & punctuation);

```
{
    /* home */
    "\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";
    "$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";

    /* end */
    "\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";
    "$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";

    /* page up/down */
    "\UF72C"  = "pageUp:";
    "\UF72D"  = "pageDown:";
}
```

Save the file, and when you next start a Cocoa app (eg Mail, TextEdit etc) you will find that <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> and <kbd>Pg Down</kbd> now work as they do on Windows.

It's well worth having a look at the whole of that article - he explains exactly how to make this file and how the bindings work, with information about the other keycodes etc.

Comment: I tried approaches like this for a while, but then got annoyed by the apps that didn't use the keybindings.  It's probably better to get used to it.  (You won't have it remapped on a school's, library's, or friend's Mac for example.)  I switch between OS X, Windows, and Linux all the time and while it took a little getting used to each of them, spending the time has been worth it.

Comment: @Benjamin:  I disagree.  I've been using a Mac for 3+ years now and still haven't adjusted.  I agree with the concept of adjusting (for instance, Cmd+c instead of Ctrl+c), but I think the home and end thing is just too much for me for whatever reason.  Also, I'm not too concerned with how I will work on friend's or library's computers, since I spend >99% of my time on my own computer.  +1 for an answer that changed the way I use my Mac!

Comment: @Benjamin: I also disagree. Having used Mac for 7+ years, I still prefer the Windows way for doing pageup/down and moving to end of line. Maybe because I use a "Win" keyboard (Razer BlackWidow) or maybe because I learned to use computer with DOS and later Windows 3.11. But in any case, my hands are used to the WinWay. :)

Comment: Cmd+Left = Home and Cmd+Right = End. Cmd+Up and Cmd+Down go to the top and bottom of the page, so not a replacement of page up and page down.

Comment: I've found that Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E are generally a lot nicer to use than Cmd+Left and Cmd+Right, especially if you change your CapsLock key to Ctrl, and they work in Terminal too.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>: Help->Search, then type any menu item text, can be just a prefix

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: put selected text in search dialog

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>: find next/previous

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>: Take a screenshot, press space for whole window screenshot

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + mouse scroller: zoom screen

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd>: sleep

Comment: You can use `<kbd>` to format keys. I've also added some HTML comments, because there's an unknown character in the last three (at least under Win7).

Comment: Thanks for the <kbd> tip :) I removed html comments, while it looks fine on my mac.

Comment: you should separate the separate keys into different keys :P

Answer (score 6):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: Go to the beginning of the line (works in every Cocoa textfield)
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: Go to the end of the line (works in every Cocoa textfield)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> : Pop up the Home folder
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> : Pop up the Desktop folder

Comment: The first two are the standard emacs keybindings, and you can use many of the standard emacs keybindings on (all?) Cocoa applications.  `ctrl+t` is a favourite one: for transposing two characters.

Comment: True. Nice one for `ctrl-t` !

Answer (score 4):

While being in the application switcher (using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>) cycle to an application by pressing <kbd>⇥</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>; then - while still holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd> - press the down arrow to see an expose view of the selected app´s windows, including minimized windows. Using the arrow keys navigate to a window you want to bring to the foreground and hit <kbd>←</kbd> to select it.

Answer (score 4):

Holding down the <kbd>⌥</kbd> while booting to select the startup volume.
Holding down <kbd>C</kbd> while booting to boot from a CD/DVD in the drive.

Comment: for anyone confused by this, 'startup volume' refers to the disk/partition to boot the OS from, not the sound level of the startup 'chime'!

Answer (score 4):

In a text area:
<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> the end of the line (like End)
<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> the beginning of the line (like Home)
<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> jump forward one word
<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> jump back one word

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: Close window (or tab).
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: Close all windows.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+click on a window copies the current window to the desktop.

This is very useful while taking screenshots without the need to crop. The rounded edges stay rounded.
Use this with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to copy the image to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

All of the shortcuts are my favorite!

Specifically (based on frequency of use) <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>: Hide application

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>:  Cycle through applications.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>:  Cycle through the current application's windows.

<kbd>⇥</kbd>: Auto fill commands and file/directory names in Terminal.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>: Take a screenshot of a selected area.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>: Take a screenshot of the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:  Copy selection

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>: Paste selection

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>: Cut selection

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> - change sound volume without 'bip' sound

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show all windows (in the current Space)

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show the desktop

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show the "current application" windows

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show the Exposé preference pane

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+V   pastes plain text, SUPER useful for copying from web pages or MS Word into email, and leaving the weird formatting behind.

Answer (score 1):

Not wholly keyboard shortcut, but holding down the Option key (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) and bringing up a system menu often provides extensive information. For instance if you are connected to wifi, hold down <kbd>⌥</kbd> and clicking on the network menu will bring up a lot of information (MAC address, IP address, signal strength, *et c*.) about the current network connection.

Holding <kbd>⌥</kbd> and clicking on the notification icon also sets your notification status to "Do not disturb"---rather useful when discussing something on your screen with colleagues and you don't want to see Messages popping up.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to order files by name (icon view)

Answer (score 0):

Zoom shortcuts, very good for presentations:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>: turn on/off zoom

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>: zoom in

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>: zoom out

Answer (score 0):

On newer keyboards, invoke Exposé to

- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show all windows (in the current Space)
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show the desktop
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show the "current application" windows
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: show the Exposé preference pane

While being in Exposé,

- cycle through windows with the arrow keys, using return to bring them into focus.
- use <kbd>⇥</kbd> and  <kbd>⇧</kbd>+ <kbd>⇥</kbd> to cycle through windows by applications (as highlighted in the Dock)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to move between Mission Control spaces (in Lion).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> Cycles through tabs in a web browser going to the right.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> Cycles through tabs in a web browser going to the left.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> Goes to the very bottom of a web page or textarea.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>  Goes to the very top of a web page or textarea.

Comment: In Chrome, you can use `⌘` + `⌥` + `←` and `⌘` + `⌥` + `→` to cycle between tabs.

Answer (score 0):

In Finder, <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> brings up the full path. If you then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Finder, you can paste the full path of a file or folder into your Terminal or elsewhere by <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

⌘+z [undo] is my favorite & the one I tell the people I support to remember if they only learn one shortcut. 
In Finder it undoes the last operation you just performed from inadvertently beginning to rename a file or folder; or undoing an unintentional drag and drop of a file or folder into the wrong folder or undoing a move to trash operation.
In applications many have multiple levels of undo which lets you step backward undoing previous edits or draws. Extremely useful in extricating yourself from sticky situations or just after having made a simple mistake.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>   turn the lights off

Comment: That doesn't turn off any lights. could you elaborate on what exact lights go off and verify it's ⌃⇧L