# Can I open the menu with keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar

With PC, alt-something opens the something in the main menu.
Does Mac have similar function? For example, is there a way to open View menu as if I click it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> - that should highlight the Apple-symbol on the main menubar.

edit: The cursor keys and Enter then allow you to navigate, drill-down and ultimately select an item - just as you can on Windows.

also - can't claim credit for this, I learnt it here on the site! [What are your favorite Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts/185#185)

Comment: You can then use arrows and letters to navigate to the other menus and their items.

Comment: @mankoff - sorry, yeah - good point! I'll edit my answer accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28168/327705 refer to this answer, it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to try: <kbd>Control ^</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>Slash /</kbd>

Advantages compared of both solution:

| Feature | <kbd>Control ^</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> | <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>Slash /</kbd> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Starts on menu side | Left side | Right side |
| Starts on menu item |  | **Help** |
| Menu state is | Highlighted | Opened |
| Hand to use | Left hand | Right hand |
| Closer to arrow keys | no | yes |
| One hand operation | no | yes |

Personally I prefer the second solution since it is closer to navigation arrow keys <kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> and the menu is already opened and only one hand, ie. right hand ☜ is involved into the operation.

Note: Some menu options are altered while holding the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key!