# Keyboard shortcut to sleep a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake

I am looking for a quick way to sleep without closing the lid, or using the mouse.

If it matters, I have Lion version OS and a MacBook Air.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press the power button, then S.

As described in this thread:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3273071?start=0&tstart=0

*The power button displays the Sleep/Restart/Shutdown dialog.  If you then press S the Mac will sleep.*

Comment: Nice! Two fewer keystrokes than my solution. :)

Comment: I would like to figure out if there is some rhyme or reason to the 'S' key activating the Sleep button. I wonder if there a consistent convention for which letters activate which buttons in osx.

Answer (score 30):

If others do have a keyboard with an eject key, you can just press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd>.

Other shortcuts:

<kbd>Control ^</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd> - Put displays to sleep
<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Control ^</kbd>+<kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd> - Restart
<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Control ^</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd> - Shut down

If others like the OP have a MacBook Air or a MacBook Pro with a power key in place of an eject key, substituting the power key for eject should work in Mountain Lion and later versions of OS X, but not in Lion.

Since Mavericks, another option is to just press the power button or power key. It now puts a Mac to sleep instead of showing a dialog with different options.

If you don't have a keyboard with an eject or power key, you can use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, VK_CONTROL, VK_OPTION, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_EJECT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
 </item>
</root>
```

Or create a workflow like this in Alfred:

[image]

Comment: Yep, this is nice. Keeping it uniform across all Macs :)

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook was renamed to Karabiner, which has been obsoleted in favor of Karabiner-Elements: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Comment: When I want my display to darken, I do CMD OPT q; this gives me  the login screen. Then ESC darkens it. How does this differ from the above solution?

Answer (score 24):

You can assign any unused key combination (like <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>) using `System Preferences` » `Keyboard` » `Keyboard Shortcuts` » `Application Shortcuts`
Click the `+` button, then under `Application`, leave `All Applications`, under `Menu Title` enter `Sleep`, and under `Keyboard Shortcut`, press <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>.

Note: For the step "under `Menu Title` enter `Sleep`", the `Sleep` is according to your language. For example, under Traditional Chinese, you should enter `睡眠`.

[image]

Another option, if you're more Terminal-inclined:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>
- Type Terminal
- push <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type `sudo shutdown -s now`

Comment: Thanks for this solution that works on a non-Mac keyboard.

Comment: Woahhh this thing is working, superb.

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me!

Comment: I didn't want to use internal laptop buttons as they don't necessarily exist on an external keyboard. I used `command+control+s`. It's a similar to the convention to lock the computer: `command+control+q`.

Comment: I'm sure my upvote of this was years ago but I'm back again and appreciating it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Press the power button. Assuming you haven't reconfigured its behaviour, it should pop up a dialog with options to Sleep, Restart, or Shutdown the laptop. The "Reopen windows when logging back in" checkbox has keyboard focus by default; hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice will put focus on the **Sleep** button - hitting the Space bar will then put the MacBook Air to sleep.

(Note that hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> will activate the dialog's default action - namely, to shut the computer down.)

Not as quick as a single keyboard shortcut, but faster than the mouse and without closing the lid. :)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that spacebar triggers the focused button. That was not obvious to me at all.

Comment: [How do you change the behavior of the power button in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/31231/8546) (2011-11-14) notes that for some users, simply pressing the power button will sleep the Mac without a dialogue.

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> (the Eject key is at your keyboard upper right corner).

Comment: Not on the new MacBook Air models. No eject key.

Comment: The power key can be substituted for eject on Mountain Lion and later versions of OS X. It works for other shortcuts like ⌃⇧⏏ as well.

Answer (score 3):

### Keyboard Shortcut

[image]

### Sleep Mac while it is running

[image]

Comment: This just turns off the display on older Macs. On the newer Macs this is the same as sleep, as far as I understand, but it might confuse people with older machines.

Answer (score 3):

I was totally happy using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) but:

> Karabiner does not work on macOS Sierra at the moment.

I got bored of waiting so I solved by myself.

**What I need?** 
I need a command line to sleep mac, and this is pretty easy:

```
pmset sleepnow
```

**Who can I run the script?** This is more boring, but not complicated:

- open automator and create a new service

[image]

- select 'run shell script' and write the above command

[image]

- save with name "sleepService" and your are in!

Now the easy part: open **System Preferences->Keyboard** and type your custom shortcut!

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I can run `pmset sleepnow` from the cli and it works but it does not work as a service.  I have tried both from within automator and not.

Comment: @GregoryArenius check if you have any key binding conflicts..

Answer (score 1):

For everyone **without** a mac keyboard, I advice you to install [**Karabiner**](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Once opened, you can go under "Change Key" tab and search for sleep:

[image]

With this option checked, now you can:

- prompt restart/sleep/shutdown dialog: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>
- force immediately sleep: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Add below to **karabiner** **complex** **modifications**. You **may** **adjust** the shortcuts as you wish. They map to the original mac shortcuts for **sleep screen** and **sleep computer**.

Currently it is ctrl + option + command + button prior to 1 on keyboard (**grave_accent_and_tilde**)

Other is ctrl + option ... you know the rest.

```
{
        "description": "momomo.com.karabiner.sleep.screen.and.sleep.computer.shortcuts",
        "manipulators": [
                {
                        "type": "basic",

                        "from":  {
                                "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde",
                                "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                                "left_control",
                                                "left_option",
                                                "left_command"
                                        ]
                                }
                        },
                        "to": {
                                "consumer_key_code": "eject",
                                "modifiers": [
                                        "left_command",
                                        "left_option"
                                ]
                        }
                },

                {
                        "type": "basic",

                        "from":  {
                                "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde",
                                "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                                "left_control",
                                                "left_option"
                                        ]
                                }
                        },
                        "to": {
                                "consumer_key_code": "eject",
                                "modifiers": [
                                        "left_control",
                                        "left_shift"
                                ]
                        }
                }

        ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (previously named KeyRemap4MacBook), you can remap your `F19` key (or any other F key for that matter) to make the computer sleep using the following [`private.xml`](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#privatexml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>F19 to Sleep</name>
    <identifier>Sleep</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::F19,
        KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_EJECT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
 </item>
</root>
```

To use a different F key, simply change all occurrences of `F19` to something else.

F19 works best for me since it's at the top right edge of the full-size wired Apple keyboard, making it hard to hit it by mistake and easy to find in the dark.