# How do you change the behavior of the power button in Lion?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake

On my Macbook Pro, whenever you press the power button it goes into sleep mode. How do I change this to do nothing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control whether pressing the power button should put your mac to sleep or present a dialog with options (sleep/restart/shut-down) using the `pmset` command. The following:

```
sudo pmset powerbutton 1
```

will put it to sleep right away (presumably your current setting) and changing `1` to `0` will present you with the dialog.

Pay attention to the fact that it's not a per-user setting, and changes the behaviour for all users. Something to keep in mind if you share the device with others. From the man page (explore it for other options):

> All changes made through pmset are saved in a persistent preferences file (per-system, not per-user) at
>        /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist

Comment: Seems this does not work for Mavericks. It gives "Usage: pmset <options>" output. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can confirm, `pmset` in Mavericks doesn't accept powerbutton arguments.

Comment: So irritating that someone clear used time to remove functionality that everybody is crying for now!

Answer (score 3):

```
defaults write com.apple.loginwindow PowerButtonSleepsSystem -bool no
```

Is working for me on 10.9.5, and gives behavior very close to how the power button used to work for me on 10.6. Though there is a bit more of a delay, it's definitely not infuriating anymore.

http://www.defaults-write.com/10-9-stop-the-power-button-from-putting-your-mac-in-stand-by-mode/

Comment: Not working for me in Sierra / macOS 10.12; nothing happens when I pressing the power button.  

OTOH, I can hit Ctrl-PowerButton to get a dialog, whether this is set to yes, no or unset.