# macOS Monterey: set power button default long-press action, possible?

Tags: macos, keyboard, sleep-wake, monterey, power-management

When long-pressing the power button, instead of showing the thing below, can I specify it to sleep immediately?

I have searched the web, but the only thing I could find was [this question for Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31231/how-do-you-change-the-behavior-of-the-power-button-in-lion), and all comments say that it no longer works.

If it is no longer possible, do write that, and I will take that as the answer.

[image]

Comment: Various solutions (such as the Opt-Cmd-Power trick) here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28164/30895

Comment: @MartinR No. My question was putting the computer to sleep by long-pressing the power button. The linked answer shows key combinations like Opt+cmd+power. So, what, there is no way to make long-press sleep?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's not exactly the same, but you can use <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd>-Power button/Media Eject to put your Mac to sleep without a prompt.