# Run `pmset sleepnow` with a hotkey?

Tags: keyboard, automator, sleep-wake, karabiner

I have a 2017 rMB and WASD CODE keyboard that I use with with an external monitor in clamshell mode. I want to put the laptop into sleep mode (not just display sleep) with a hotkey when the laptop is closed.

This *can* be achieved using CMD+OPT+Power when the laptop is *open*.

When the laptop is closed this is currently impossible since Karabiner Elements won't recognize the power button (and so I can't remap it).

I was thinking there might be a way to set CMD+OPT+Pause to fire `pmset sleepnow`. Is this possible with Karbiner Elements and/or Automator?

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

UPDATE: Using the accepted answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340955/how-to-skip-cancel-continue-when-running-shell-script-with-automator/340978#340978) for the solution.

Comment: wow, I did not know about the CMD+OPT+Power

Comment: will this work for you ..https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28169/46541