# How to skip 'Cancel' 'Continue' when running shell script with automator?

Tags: applescript, command-line, automator, script

I'm trying to run `pmset sleepnow` linked to a keyboard shortcut with automator. When I use the shortcut, it's giving me a 'Cancel' or 'Continue' prompt. Anyway to skip this so the script just runs when I press the key combo?

Comment: Like ʀ2ᴅ2, I too cannot reproduce your issue. I'd suggest you edit your question to include additional information to help us diagnose/troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate your prompt issue if I code the `sleepnow` in a `do shell`.

- Launch Automator
- Go to `File > New`
- Select Service and click <kbd>Choose</kbd>
- Select "No input" in drop-down list
- Select in drop-down list "Any application"
- Select "Run AppleScript" and double-click or drag and drop
- Replace the script with a `do shell`
- Save the service
- Add service in keyboard

[image]

The code:

```
try
    display notification "Attempting sleep"
    delay 2
    set result to do shell script "pmset sleepnow"
on error result
    display dialog result
end try
```

The service with shortcut:

[image]

System specs:

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 on Macbook Pro

Comment: There should not be a need to use a Run AppleScript action when all that's needed is a Run ShellScript action with simply `pmset sleepnow` as the command.

Comment: Well if there was an error to occur it will render the error.