# sleep shortcut on macos 12

Tags: shortcut, monterey, shortcuts-app

I am new to macos 12 and I could not figure out how to set up a shortcut to put the system to sleep (or shut down), using the 'shortcuts' app

thanks for help

Comment: not found in gallery either

Comment: Which Mac do you have? The ones with TouchID can be locked with the TouchID button, which will then make them sleep shortly after.

Comment: If you just need a quick way to sleep your Mac, use the keyboard shortcuts documented in https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT201236.

Comment: @Tetsujin correct -- ok, I was wondering indeed whether it goes to sleep , and when ...

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, the shortcuts are pretty stable [across Mac versions for sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28164/5472) and [other functions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22HT201236%22).

The iOS app shortcut that came to macOS is for automation and workflows so that might cause some search collisions or confusion.

Comment: ok -- as I do not have the eject button, I will figure something else out, but the touchID button or lock shortcut might be already enough -- thanks anyway

Comment: F12 and the power button are equivalent to the dedicated eject key in most cases @jjrr