# Using the keyboard to bring up the File, Edit, View... menus

Tags: finder, menu-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I open the menu with keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/can-i-open-the-menu-with-keyboard)

In windows, in most applications, if I hit Alt+F it opens the "File" menu.  If it hit Alt+E, it brings up the Edit menu.  Is there an OS X equivalent?

This is a handy way to get to those windows and choose an option without grabbing the mouse.  I know there are keyboard shortcuts for things inside those menus (say Command+C for copy).  But, is there a way to simply bring up the menu so I an see what's in there, then choose my option with arrow keys and return?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily; by default, under System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard, an option involving the "f" function keys may be unchecked. If this is the case, check it, and then click the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab. Go to "Keyboard & Text Input" and find the command for "move focus to the menu bar". Use this command (I believe it's <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> by default). Then, use the <kbd>F</kbd> key for file, the <kbd>E</kbd> key for edit, etc. (or use arrow keys) and hit enter (or down) to show the menu.

Comment: this takes me to the top right context (wifi, clock, search, and so on) not the file, edit, view and such context

Comment: F2 works for me. You don't have to check the "F" key option if you are willing to use the "fn" key on your mac keyboard.