# System-wide Keyboard Shortcut for Moving to Sidebar/Next Column

Tags: keyboard

I've been on a bit of a Keyboard-only kick lately, enabled chiefly due to the [Chrome Keyboard Shortcut Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/abcekjakjehkpheoaadhkjfcdodpjbgk), and I've begun bumping into a few difficult situations in everyday Desktop App use.

In applications like iTunes, or Code Editors, they have a unified sidebar with categorically organized content. iTunes has categories for your library, other people's libraries, your device, and playlists, Coda has a file picker, etc. But what is the easiest way to move keyboard focus to these sidebars? My current solution is to alternate <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>▼</kbd> aimlessly until I see an item on the sidebar highlighted. Needless to say this is frustrating and can lead to unintended changes being made in content panes.

I notice that most all apps have a function to hide the sidebar in the app menus, but restoring it doesn't move the focus to the sidebar.

I've looked at the [Mac OS X Keyboard Shortcut Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts) but didn't find what I was looking for. Is there some kind of a global shortcut that will move focus between different interface elements, easily? Reliably?

Comment: Just keyboard or track/touch pad based ones too ?

Comment: Just keyboard. This is a desktop question, not an iOS question. With a mouse, I can just click in the sidebar. The point is to avoid the mouse.

Comment: Nice extension!

Comment: Something tells me that this feature doesn't exist, and that's sad. If I'm particularly motivated enough, I may write this up at rdar://. I'm going to accept the only answer I got, because it, well, actually tried to solve the issue! :).

Comment: Thx :-) Let us know when you got something working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking outside the box:

If the only reason you want the keyboard shortcut, is to avoid your mouse, have you considered a [trackpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick) keyboard?

Because I had [RSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury) in the past, [trackpoint keyboards are about the only ones I can use](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/switchresx-helped-me-switch-my-mac-machine-to-1360x768-and-1888x1062/) (even at clients, I usually bring my keyboard, or work from my laptop that has such a keyboard).

The big upside of those keyboards is that you don't have to take your hand of the keyboard in order to use the mouse.
For [trackpads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchpad) I still need to (somehow using my thumb is far less accurate on trackpads than using my index finger, o I still need to lift my hand for pointing).

It takes a little while to get used to a trackpoint, but I can't do without them any more.
USB trackpoint keyboards work equally well on Mac and PC.

--jeroen

Comment: I want a keyboard shortcut because (when implemented correctly), the keyboard is blazingly fast, and more accurate than a mouse could ever hope to be. I understand that you can't map everything back to the keyboard, but when I can, I would love to use it. Again, reference the Chrome extension I linked in my post, that extension has been a boon (except in some places on this network, imagine that). I use a MacBook Pro and find myself nudging the trackpad occasionally, but again, the mouse is imprecise (to a point) by definition. I do miss trackpoints though, always preferred those to touchpads.

Comment: thanks for your clarification; I agree that keyboard-only is way faster than any pointing device for repetitive tasks.

Comment: See the comment on the original post, thanks for your answer.